# Return array of model objects instead of array of arrays in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter model:

```
<?php
class Person_model extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function list_persons() {
        $query = $this->db->get('persons');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function foobar() {
        return 'Custom function here';
    }
}
?>
```

The function `list_persons()` is quite self-explained. It fetches all results from `persons` database table.

Currently it returns results in a list of arrays, like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "1"
    ["first_name"] => string(6) "Test 1"
  }
  [1] => array(3) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "2"
    ["first_name"] => string(6) "Test 2"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to let the function `list_persons()` to return:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => Person_model {
    "id" => 1
    "first_name" => "Test 1"
  }
  [1] => Person_model {
    "id" => 2
    "first_name" => "Test 2"
  }
}
```

so that I can use the custom functions I wrote in the `Person_model`, such as:

```
foreach($this->person_model->list_persons() as $person) {
    echo $person->foobar();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your `list_person()` method like this (use `$query->result()`):

```
public function list_persons() {
    $query = $this->db->get('persons');
    return $query->result('Person_model');
}
```

Comment: Nice. However, the class returned is a `stdClass` instead of a `Person_model`, which the `foobar()` cannot be called. Any advise?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Pass a string which represents the model class to the `$query->result()`, for example `$query->result('Person_model')` to convert it to your model class.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome! I never knew about this! Thank you @RendyEkoPrastiyo